# Module sklearn.tree_tree has no attribute DTYPE.

Tags: python, tree, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import tree
#Just a basic program. I am just a beginner.
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

X = [[190,84,9], [180,80,9], [175,67,8],[165,60,6],[180,64,7],[180,74,8],[154,56,5],[162,60,8],
      [184,76,9],[142,46,5],[164,69,8]]
Y = ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
     "Female"]

clf = clf.fit(X,Y)

prediction = clf.predict([169,58,8])

print(prediction)
```

This is the python code that I have. I have successfully installed the packages, yet I am getting this error. I use the Anaconda distribution with the spyder editor.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the complete error. Also give the output of `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: Post the complete traceback error

Comment: Sorry friends, the error was with the value passed for predict(). It's required to give a 2D array and instead, I gave a 1-D array. Sorry again.

Comment: Thanks, @AbdealiJK for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The error with this code is with the argument passed for the predict function.
The corrected code is

```
from sklearn import tree
#Just a basic program. I am just a beginner.
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

X = [[190,84,9], [180,80,9], [175,67,8],[165,60,6],[180,64,7],[180,74,8],[154,56,5],[162,60,8],
      [184,76,9],[142,46,5],[164,69,8]]
Y = ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
     "Female"]

clf = clf.fit(X,Y)

prediction = clf.predict([[169,58,8]])

print(prediction)
```

And it gives the correct output as ['Female'].
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the import statement

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

X = [[190,84,9], [180,80,9], [175,67,8],[165,60,6],[180,64,7],[180,74,8],[154,56,5],[162,60,8],
      [184,76,9],[142,46,5],[164,69,8]]
Y = ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
     "Female"]

clf = clf.fit(X,Y)

prediction = clf.predict([169,58,8])

print(prediction)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai for your suggestion, but DecisionTreeClassifier cannot be imported is the error that I am getting. But the problem has been solved as I have mentioned in the previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: the error was with the value passed for predict(). It's required to give a 2D array and instead, I gave a 1-D array. Sorry again.

Comment: @Ish ... Can you post your answer and mark it as correct so that others are not misguided when they see this question